# Property 'set' does not exist on type 'IonicStorageModule'

Tags: ionic2

> Typescript Error Property 'set' does not exist on type
>   'IonicStorageModule'.
>
> C:/Users/Kamleshutube/HDKProject/src/pages/login/login.ts
>         this.storage.set('mydata','kamlesh');
>              Typescript Error Property 'get' does not exist on type 'IonicStorageModule'.
>   C:/Users/Kamleshutube/HDKProject/src/pages/login/login.ts

```
this.storage.get('mydata',(data)=>{
    console.log(data);
```

Comment: can you post your full code?

Answer (score 3):

IonicStorageModule is only for app.module.ts

to set storage you need to import below code in your page

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
```

and add it in constructor then set using `this.storage.set(key,value);`

also donot set `IonicStorageModule` as a providers

and set     `IonicStorageModule.forRoot()` in imports
like this

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    SwingModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
```